# remove a lesser duplicate

Tags: kdb

In KDB, I have the following table:

```
q)tab:flip `items`sales`prices!(`nut`bolt`cam`cog`bolt`screw;6 8 0 3 0n 0n;10  20 15 20 0n 0n)
q)tab

items sales prices
------------------
nut   6     10
bolt  8     20
cam   0     15
cog   3     20
bolt
screw
```

In this table, there are 2 duplicate items (bolt). However since the first 'bolt' contains more information. I would like to remove the 'lesser' bolt.

FINAL RESULT:

```
items sales prices
------------------
nut   6     10
bolt  8     20
cam   0     15
cog   3     20
screw
```

As far as I understand, If I used the 'distinct' function its not deterministic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do it is to fill forward by item, then `bolt` will inherit the previous values.

```
q)update fills sales,fills prices by items from tab
items sales prices
------------------
nut   6     10
bolt  8     20
cam   0     15
cog   3     20
bolt  8     20
screw
```

This can also be done in functional form where you can pass the table and `by` columns:

```
{![x;();(!). 2#enlist(),y;{x!fills,/:x}cols[x]except y]}[tab;`items]
```

If "more information" means "least nulls" then you could count the number of nulls in each row and only return those rows by item that contain the fewest:

```
q)select from @[tab;`n;:;sum each null tab] where n=(min;n)fby items
items sales prices n
--------------------
nut   6     10     0
bolt  8     20     0
cam   0     15     0
cog   3     20     0
screw              2
```

Although would not recommend this approach as it requires working with rows rather than columns.

Comment: regarding the fill forward method. What if the first encountered item 'bolt' is have null values? would the fill forward have the adverse effect of feeling subsequent 'bolt' as nulls?

Comment: No, it is only null values that get filled.

Comment: So I tried this command: q)update fills * by items from tab, with intention of filling forward every field with a matching item. It did not work, do I have to specify per field? Many tks!

Comment: Unfortunately `*` doesn't work in q-sql but you can make use of [functional form](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/funsql/). To see how a query looks in functional form you can use `parse`, e.g. `parse "select from x"`. The following function will allow you to fill forward by one or multiple `by` columns: `{![x;();(!). 2#enlist(),y;{x!fills,/:x}cols[x]except y]}` where `x` is the table and `y` are the columns. Ill add this function to my answer to as it will be easier to read there.

Answer (score 1):

Because those two rows contain different data, they are considered distinct.

It depends on how you define "more information".  You would probably need to provide more examples, but some possibilities:

**Delete rows with null sales value**

```
q)delete from tab where null sales
items sales prices
------------------
nut   6     10    
bolt  8     20    
cam   0     15    
cog   3     20
```

**Retrieve rows with max sales value for each item**

```
q)select from tab where (sales*prices) = (max;sales*prices) fby items
items sales prices
------------------
nut   6     10    
bolt  8     20    
cam   0     15    
cog   3     20
```

Comment: thanks so much for reply. I have edited the question little bit. Instead of using a max value, can we favor the non-null value so it can work for all types?